# Git LFS with Artifactory Workflow

Tags: workflow, artifactory, git-lfs

I've been reading the Artifactory documentation and I'm struggling to understand how a workflow with Git LFS would work or why I would want to use Git LFS with it.  Would you only use Git LFS with it if you want to selectively download full large files?

In my case I have a bunch of large files which I tried uploading into Github after tracking with Git LFS.  The company admins said my repo was too large for Github and suggested using Artifactory.

I'm learning to upload my large files into my namespace in Artifactory.  When I have updated versions of these files in the future, can't I just upload them into Artifactory?  When I want to download these files, I'm going to want the complete large file.  I just want a way to get the latest version of the large files but also have the option of going back in history and getting a previous version.  Should I just use Artifactory by itself then?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a git project with resource directory containing 1000 image files, each is about 1MB of data.
If you want it to be tracked by git you will have to push all of them, and make your VCS full of big files, pushing more than 1GB of things you probably doesn't really need tracking.

git-lfs will replace those files with a "bookmark" file that may look something like this:

> version https://git-lfs.github.com/spec/v1 oid
>   sha256:4665a5ea423c2713d436b5ee50593a9640e0018c1550b5a0002f74190d6caea8
>   size 1000000

the actual file will be stored in artifactory, the "bookmark" file will be stored in git. when a user pulls the files, the client first  pulls from git, and then download from artifactory using the data left by git-lfs replaced file.

this way you will benefit all of git possibilities without spamming your branches with tons of unnecessary large files. all of your git commands will work out of the box. (assuming git-lfs properly configured)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a the exact situation that Git LFS was designed for.

You could simply upload all of your large files into Artifactory and update them whenever one changed, but this will require a lot of manual processing, eg downloading the correct versions of files, structuring your repositories in such a way as to make the versioning clear, etc.

Alternatively you could just keep everything in a Git repository, but you will run into trouble with the size of the repo, whether it is the host complaining or just the time taken to download all of the large files every time you clone the repo.

Git LFS is intended to solve these problems. You have the same Git interface and version history, but the large files themselves are stored somewhere more appropriate, in this case Artifactory. This allows you to continue working in exactly the same way as you have been, but removes the problems you've been facing with large files.